# AJAX: sending xmlhttp requests in a loop ... but all the responses are not received

Tags: php, ajax

I have this function below and I call that function in a loop 
I get the alert n times but only n-1 or sometimes n-2 responses

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                        {
                            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                            //document.getElementById("warnings_panel").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                }

                alert("in ajax) 

                xmlhttp.open("GET","getresponse.php?start="+ start
    + "&end=" + end,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be depending on a single global `xmlhttp` variable. Don't do that.

Comment: what should I do ... I just started ajax ... could u please elaborate

Comment: That smells like W3Schools code. Don't use them. Do use a library that abstracts the API to something similar and takes care of cross browser issues. http://microjs.com/#ajax or http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/io/ or http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: you say that i can solve the problem if i use non global variable ... could you guide me on how can i do that

Comment: Using a global xmlhttp is a bad practise. It is a good source of race conditions, which is probably what is going on here.

Comment: A decent API will take care of all sorts of things (like readyState tests) and leave you with simpler, easier to read code with less opportunity for things to break. You could roll your own, but using more widely tested code leaves fewer chances for you to screw up.

Comment: Is there an easier way to restrict simultaneous AJAX requests to 1 ?

Comment: Who said anything about limiting the number of simultaneous requests? (Using a global **won't** do that, it will just muck up the references in the callbacks so they don't point at the object you want).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are sending something unique with each request. IE sometimes caches AJAX request responses - if you append something unique to your query (such as a counter that increments with each request), it will prevent IE from returning the cached response.

Comment: but I dont receive the cached response too ... i m receiving one or two responses less than n

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
function ajaxping() {

     var xmlhttp ={};

             if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

                 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

                         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

                 }

                 else

                 {// code for IE6, IE5

                         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                 }

                 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()

                 {

                         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)

                         {

                         var status = xmlhttp.status;

                         var isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 1223 || status === 304;

                                                                         if(isSuccess) {

                                                                         alert("got success response");

                                                                         }

                       }

                 }



                 alert("in ajax");



                 xmlhttp.open("GET","test.html");

                 xmlhttp.send();

}



var func = function() {

for(var i=0;i<10;i++){

ajaxping();

}

}

func();

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: the code works ... but just misses a few responses so i dont think this is the issue

Comment: this is the issue. ie sometimes returns 304 and 1223 status codes. We arrived at this solution after working for a week.

Comment: all the above said status means success response not only 200. covers all browsers.

Comment: You overwrite `xmlhttp` several times, but every one of your `onreadystatechange` event handlers will reference the last one. This is a nasty race condition.

Comment: xmlhttp request is a local variable declared above the how come onreadystatechange will reference to the last one. Please read the code once again or try it out on your machine

Comment: It is local to ajaxping. Inside ajaxping there is a for loop that assigns multiple XHR objects to it one after the other. Each XHR object has an onreadystatechange event handler that references the late XHR object (i.e. the one stored in that variable when the response comes back). If you were going to use this approach then the for loop needs to be **outside** the function call not inside the function.

Comment: Before assigning the onreadystate method i am assigning that variable to either ActiveXObject or XMLHttpRequest. As it is running in the loop new variable will be created every time.

Comment: No. The variable is created in the same function as the loop, so the same variable will be used each time. It will be overwritten with a new XHR object each time, but the onreadystatechange handler will reference the **variable** not the object that the variable contained at the time the hander was assigned.

Comment: Your clarification is wrong. Each time I loop through a new variable will be created. You can console.log xmlhttp every time and see that it is an empty object.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Want ever David told is right. Modified my code a bit

Answer (score 1):

When you are using loop to send ajax request and using a single object, there is a possibility that the second or concecutive request can be sent even before the response for the first request is sent..

So use individual objects to send individual requests..

The sample code should be like this..

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        eval("xmlhttp"+i+"=new XMLHttpRequest()");
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5      
                }
                eval("xmlhttp"+i+".onreadystatechange=function(i)");
                function(var obj)
                {
                 //function contents
                }

                alert("in ajax) 

                // assign responsetext and send code
}
```

Comment: what does eval() do? could u please tell me I am relatively new at this

Comment: eval just evaluates the string inside this function.. see here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp for function reference  and the important thing here is not eval and the concept creating individual objects..

Comment: okay thanks i was just trying this approach...... can u tell me whether it is necessary to pass i to the function eval("xmlhttp"+i+".onreadystatechange=function(i)")

Comment: Aigh! Don't use eval! Either split things out into a different function so that you get a local instance of the variable for each request or learn to use `this`. (And when you do want sequentially numbered variables (which are the wrong solution for this problem) then use an array!)

Comment: can u give some example code on how to solve it with array of xmlhttp array

Comment: Arhg! I said **don't** use an array. An array is good when you need a sequence of variables, which you don't.

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getresponse.php?start="+ start
    + "&end=" + end,true);
```

In the above line you have mentioned true as the last parameter instead of that use false.

So the AJAX becomes a synchronous call, the interprter will wait till the responses arrives.

But for every response check for null.

Comment: someone else did it...really ppl should leave a reason for vote down ... I did vote up ... I dont like ppl discouraging someone who tries to answer .... though i haven't checked ur solution coz i have modified my code according to previous answers ... I willl try it in a while

Comment: @koool : You r altitude is also cool. I am not asking to you. But before you up vote me someone else down voted me without any reason. Hence I asked for reason.

Comment: @Ankit ... hey man your solution works but ... that makes the AJAX synchronous and the advantage of AJAX is lost ... though if I do not get any other asynchronous working solution I will accept this ... Thank you very much for the Answer ... I really appreciate the effort... I hope u are well rewarded

Comment: @koool : Do the response from server comes late?

Comment: Synchronous XKR locks up JS processing and should never be used. File it next to `eval`.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is a late response. The last parameter in xmlhttp.open function represents asynchronous, not synchronous value. So the INTERPRETER WILL WAIT FOR THE RESPONSE IF THE VALUE IS SET TO FALSE, NOT TRUE.